# How to get the post ID associated with a Woocommerce Subscription

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am desperately trying to programmatically get the post ID associated with a WooCommerce Subscription object. I am starting from the user id, and trying to request the database using the get_posts function. A call using the `get_users_subscriptions` works but the objects returned do not include their `ID`, only the associated `order_id` or `product_id`.

```
$subscriptions = WC_Subscriptions_Manager::get_users_subscriptions(
    $current_user->ID
);

$subscription_posts = get_posts( array(
      'orderby'     => 'date',
      'order'       => 'ASC',
      'numberposts' => 1,
      'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
      'meta_value'  => $current_user->ID,
      'post_type'   => 'shop_subscription'
) );
```

The `get_post` request is sadly returning an empty array. Do you see something wrong in my request ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find an easy solution so I went with a SQL request based on the order_id contained in the subscription object I get using the call of:

```
$subscriptions = WC_Subscriptions_Manager::get_users_subscriptions(
   $current_user->ID
);
```

The $wpdb call looks like the following:

```
$subscription_id = $wpdb->get_var(
     "SELECT ID
      FROM $wpdb->posts
      WHERE `post_type`='shop_subscription'
      AND `post_parent`=$first_order->ID
      ORDER BY `post_date` ASC
      LIMIT 1;"
);
```

If it helps someone, you're welcome !

Answer (score 1):

I've achieved the same thing with the following code, if you are using the wp rest APIs, it will also add a property to the response:

```
add_action(
  'rest_api_init',
  function() {

    // add _subscription_id to wc-order response
    register_rest_field( 'shop_order', '_subscription_id', [
      'get_callback' => function ($order) {
        $subscriptionIds = wcs_get_subscriptions_for_order( $order['id'] );

        foreach( $subscriptionIds as $subscriptionId => $subscription )
          if($subscription->order->id == $order['id']) break;

        foreach( $order['meta_data'] as $meta )
          if ($meta->key === '_subscription_renewal') {
            $metaSubscriptionId = $meta->value; break;
          }

        return $subscriptionId ?: (int) $metaSubscriptionId;
      },
      'update_callback'   => null,
      'schema'            => null,
    ]);
  }
);
```